# JavaScript Linter in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, object-oriented, stack

I wrote a simple Linter that checks for matching opening and closing braces for one line of JavaScript. It utilizes a stack to store opening braces found in the line, then compares the first closing brace found to pop(). I wrote this in Java based on a Ruby version in *"A Common-Sense Guide to Data Structures and Algorithms"* by Jay Wengrow.

There are three syntax errors for the braces:

- An opening brace doesn't have a closing brace
- A closing brace doesn't have an opening brace
- A closing brace is not the same as the opening brace that preceded it.

I wrote three methods to check for the errors. Two of the methods return a boolean:

```
private boolean isOpeningBrace(Character brace) {
        if ((brace == '(') || (brace == '{') || (brace == '[')) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
}

private boolean isClosingBrace(Character brace) {
    if ((brace == ')') || (brace == '}') || brace == ']') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The third method is void but manipulates the stack:

```
private void isAMatch(Character openingBrace, Character closingBrace) {
    if ((openingBrace == '(') && (closingBrace == ')')) {
        System.out.println(Messages.IS_A_MATCH.message + openingBrace + " " + closingBrace);
        openingBracesStack.pop();
    } else if ((openingBrace == '{') && (closingBrace == '}')) {
        System.out.println(Messages.IS_A_MATCH.message + openingBrace + " " + closingBrace);
        openingBracesStack.pop();
    } else if ((openingBrace == '[') && (closingBrace == ']')) {
        System.out.println(Messages.IS_A_MATCH.message + openingBrace + " " + closingBrace);
        openingBracesStack.pop();
    } else {
        System.out.println(Messages.NOT_A_MATCH.message + openingBrace + " " + closingBrace);
    }
}
```

However, all other stack operations and message delivery occur in the linter method:

```
public void linter(String string) {

    if (string.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(Messages.STRING_IS_EMPTY.message);
        return;
    }

    char[] characters = string.toCharArray();

    for (char currentCharacter : characters) {
        if (isOpeningBrace(currentCharacter)) {
            openingBracesStack.push(currentCharacter);
        } else if (isClosingBrace(currentCharacter)) {
            if (openingBracesStack.peek() == null) {
                System.out.println(Messages.NO_OPENING_BRACE.message + currentCharacter);
            } else {
                isAMatch(openingBracesStack.peek(), currentCharacter);
            }
        }
    }

    if (openingBracesStack.peek() != null) {
        do {
            System.out.println(Messages.NO_CLOSING_BRACE.message + openingBracesStack.pop());
        } while (openingBracesStack.peek() != null);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Lint complete.");
    }

}
```

This doesn't feel well organized. I'm considering two options:

1. Changing the first two methods (isOpeningBrace and isClosingBrace) to handle the stack operations and messages to match the third method
2. Changing the third method isAMatch to a boolean return in order to keep all stack operations and messages in the linter method.

The first option, to me, seems to violate the "do one thing" per function: a boolean operation, a stack operation, and presenting a message.

On the other hand, the second option seems to make the linter method more confusing to follow.

Which way follows best practices?

Here is the entire class:

```
public class Linter {

private enum Messages {
    NO_OPENING_BRACE("No opening brace to match closing brace: "),
    NO_CLOSING_BRACE("No closing brace was found to match: "),
    NOT_A_MATCH("Closing brace does not match opening brace: "),
    IS_A_MATCH("Opening and closing braces found: "),
    STRING_IS_EMPTY("No text found to lint.");


    private final String message;

    Messages(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}

private final Stack<Character> openingBracesStack = new Stack<>();

public void linter(String string) {

    if (string.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(Messages.STRING_IS_EMPTY.message);
        return;
    }

    char[] characters = string.toCharArray();

    for (char currentCharacter : characters) {
        if (isOpeningBrace(currentCharacter)) {
            openingBracesStack.push(currentCharacter);
        } else if (isClosingBrace(currentCharacter)) {
            if (openingBracesStack.peek() == null) {
                System.out.println(Messages.NO_OPENING_BRACE.message + currentCharacter);
            } else {
                isAMatch(openingBracesStack.peek(), currentCharacter);
            }
        }
    }

    if (openingBracesStack.peek() != null) {
        do {
            System.out.println(Messages.NO_CLOSING_BRACE.message + openingBracesStack.pop());
        } while (openingBracesStack.peek() != null);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Lint complete.");
    }

}

private boolean isOpeningBrace(Character brace) {
    if ((brace == '(') || (brace == '{') || (brace == '[')) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

private boolean isClosingBrace(Character brace) {
    if ((brace == ')') || (brace == '}') || brace == ']') {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

private void isAMatch(Character openingBrace, Character closingBrace) {
    if ((openingBrace == '(') && (closingBrace == ')')) {
        System.out.println(Messages.IS_A_MATCH.message + openingBrace + " " + closingBrace);
        openingBracesStack.pop();
    } else if ((openingBrace == '{') && (closingBrace == '}')) {
        System.out.println(Messages.IS_A_MATCH.message + openingBrace + " " + closingBrace);
        openingBracesStack.pop();
    } else if ((openingBrace == '[') && (closingBrace == ']')) {
        System.out.println(Messages.IS_A_MATCH.message + openingBrace + " " + closingBrace);
        openingBracesStack.pop();
    } else {
        System.out.println(Messages.NOT_A_MATCH.message + openingBrace + " " + closingBrace);
    }
}
}
```